# Ping "no resources" - what can cause that?

Tags: c++, winapi, networking

I have a strange problem - after my C++ application runs for 39 hours on Windows XP, the network is broken and the application fails. Seen that several times. When I try to "`ping localhost`", the prompt says *"no resources*". I found [this thread](http://www.hardwareforums.com/threads/ping-responds-no-resources.17093/) in Internet, where people advice to make "`ipconfig` /`renew`".

The thing is I just want to know, what actions (Windows API calls) causes that. I'm nearly 100% sure that the problem is in the network card (because the other card works well), but I just want to understand, what my actions cause that.

Unforunately, my application consists of megabytes of code, so I can't just uncomment a few lines to see if I can reproduce error now.

Is there any list of Windows API calls that are executed by network card driver? For instance, ["sendto"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is most likely executed by driver, because it sends data to network.

Is there any test (like Acid test for browsers), which can show if network driver does not behave correctly?

Comment: I'm extremely skeptical the problem is a network card or its driver and testing them is probably a waste of time.  The problem is your code, most likely a socket, memory or handle leak. Simple tools like netstat and task manager will probably tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Agreed. I'm even more sceptical that it has anything to do with DHCP leases and renewals either.

Answer (score 2):

It kind of sounds like you've run out of sockets.  Are you sure you're freeing the sockets once you've used them?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I just wrote a simple test in which I create sockets but do not close them with "closesocket". The system behaves differently. I can not even "ping localhost", because the prompt says "'ping' is not recognized as an internal or external command". Next time I see the problem I will try to execute an app which just creates a socket and see what error it will show.

Comment: Sure, extend that to "socket or some other limited resource". It also sounds a bit like this: http://www.recurity-labs.com/content/pub/Microsoft_Windows_CVE-2009-1926_MS09-048.txt or this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296845(v=bts.10).aspx .

Comment: In any case, the thing to look at first is your program -- make sure that you are allowing created network objects to go out of scope, or `delete` them explicitly, so that resources can be reclaimed.

Comment: Everything is correct with sockets. I can create a socket, but when I ping localhost I see the same error "No resources".

Comment: @Graf, the trick here is going to be finding out what resource you've run out of.  Can you tell us anything more about the application?

Comment: @Graf: If a process runs out of file descriptors (sockets here) this does not necessarily affect newly created processes.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your network card is updated with latest driver or re install the driver and then restart the machine once.